# FFMPEG - Adjust DrawText Based on the Length of the Video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, scrolling

I am creating a video with a DrawText, that vertically scrolls from down to up. The `text.txt` file contains several lines of text. Is it possible to adjust the scrolling of the text based on the length of the video?

Currently, when I try with the following code, the text scroll finishes earlier than the video, or it is too slow.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black@0.0:s=1280x720,format=rgba -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:30 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/fonts/arial.ttf:fontsize=16:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2+20:y=h-40*t:line_spacing=60:textfile='text.txt'" -y output.mp4`

Is there a way to mathematically adjust the x, y or any other attributes so that it finishes the scrolling exactly at the end of the video?

Thanks.
Note: You can create any simple text.txt file to test this code.

Comment: By saving the text to an image and then stretching that image to same width as video

Comment: Do you mean that the length of the video is known from advance (90 seconds for example)? It should be close to `y=h-h/90*t`

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you would like the text width to be the same as the video screen width. But indeed yes, if you know the video length in advance you can manage to have the text scoll over the video and finishing exactly as the video ends...

Comment: Would that be as expected? https://files.catbox.moe/8iwdvl.gif

Answer (score 0):

The formula for making a text show up from the buttom screen and disapear on the top in 90 seconds would be:

H-(t-0)*(H+th)/90

- H = Video Hight (this is the starting point)
- (t-0) determines the starting time ex (t-5) would wait 5 secs
- (H+th) the distance the text should move: Text Hight + Video Hight
- /90 the time it should take

Some code to test in ffplay:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i "color=color=yellow:size=700x500,drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':fontsize=20:x=(W-tw)-10:y=(H-th)-10,drawtext=text='SOME TEXT':fontfile='c\:\\windows\\fonts\\ariblk.ttf':fontcolor=red:fontsize=20:x=(W-tw)/2:y=H-(t-0)*(H+th)/90"
```

GIF: https://files.catbox.moe/8iwdvl.gif

Comment: I tried this code, but I keep getting an error message, `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)`.

Comment: Please try now, I updated the answer, I guess you need the whole path to the fontfile instead of font='arial black' for some reason...

Comment: No Luck. I confirmed that arial.ttf exists and corrected the fontfile path, but still same error. `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

Comment: Well than try ffmpeg with the same comand you used, except you change the formula for y=H-(t-0)*(H+th)/90

Comment: Even, ffmpeg gives same error. It must be on my system, let me try few tests and will respond here. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Maybe some of these fixes can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54887005/ffmpeg-fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file-error-windows